# Cannot move PTU46 on Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

my robot has a Flir PTU46 ( http://wiki.ros.org/ptu46 ).

I'm using this Ros node https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/wu_ptu in order to use it.
Unfortunately, when I try to public a /ptu/cmd the PTU never moves.

Has anybody used this PTU?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162556/cannot-move-ptu46-on-fuerte/) by [hisdudeness](https://answers.ros.org/users/2212/hisdudeness/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved with

rostopic pub -1 /ptu/cmd sensor_msgs/JointState '{ header: {frame_id: '' }, name: ['tilt,pan'], position: [-0,-0], velocity: [0.6,0.6], effort: [1,1]}'

---

Originally posted by [hisdudeness](https://answers.ros.org/users/2212/hisdudeness/) with karma: 51 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0